# How to call Microsoft Graph REST API with groovy-wslite

Tags: rest, groovy, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call Microsoft Graph API on groovy script using Java libraries. However, even though partly success, I still have some serious issues using it within my current project, so I think about trying to call the the REST API using groovy-wslite.

This is my current code for getting access token:

```
def authorizeHost = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"
def authorizePath = "/${azureSetting.getTenantID()}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
try {
    RESTClient client = new RESTClient(authorizeHost)
    def params = [
            "client_id":azureSetting.getClientID(),
            "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
            "response_type": "code"
        ]
    def response = client.post(
        path: authorizePath,
    )
    {
        type ContentType.JSON
        json    params
        
    }
    LOGGER.info("Success: " + (response.statusCode == 200));
    LOGGER.info("Output: (" + response.contentType + ") " + response.text);
} catch (RESTClientException e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    LOGGER.info("Error: " + sw.toString());
}
```

The response from the log:

```
AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'.
```

How can I change the above code, so that Microsoft Graph REST API can recognize my sending content and send back the access token.

UPDATE: After trying around, I found out that the body os post method should be as below:

```
type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
urlenc client_id: azureSetting.getClientID(), 
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", 
    response_type: "code"
```

Comment: Are you sure that `azureSetting.getClientID()` returns non-empty value?

Comment: @daggett Yes, I have checked. That method is the one I wrote to get setting value from encrypted file. There is no problem with return value of this method. I think the problem is the content of the REST API request that I create with groovy-wslite that not ft the requirement from Microsoft. The MS website doesn't give much help either. this is how they describe the request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#2-get-authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#token-request your request should have `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

you are trying to send json instead

here is your code but pointing to a test httpbin.org server and it could show what exactly you are sending to server

there is a minor change: `ContentType.JSON` -> `ContentType.URLENC`

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.3', transitive=false)

import wslite.rest.*
//just for test
def azureSetting = [ getClientID:{-> "12345"} ]
def LOGGER = [info:{x-> println x}]
//redefined host and url
def authorizeHost = "HTTP://httpbin.org"
def authorizePath = "/post"

try {
    RESTClient client = new RESTClient(authorizeHost)
    def params = [
            "client_id":azureSetting.getClientID(),
            "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
            "response_type": "code"
        ]
    def response = client.post(
        path: authorizePath,
    )
    {
        type ContentType.URLENC // <-- THE ONLY CHANGE IN YOUR CODE
        json    params
        
    }
    LOGGER.info("Success: " + (response.statusCode == 200));
    LOGGER.info("Output: (" + response.contentType + ") " + response.text);
} catch (RESTClientException e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    LOGGER.info("Error: " + sw.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this, but the result is the same. It is kind of weird that I am unable to find any sample code for this kind of stuff from Microsoft.

Comment: the code works well for me. if you still have the same error `The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'` - check that you are providing correct client_id parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I have found the misstake in my code. Please check the update.