# Trying to connect to MSGraph API using Groovy

Tags: groovy, microsoft-graph-api

Updating with current status.

After changing the def url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantId + '/oauth2/v2.0/token' to def url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantId + '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?', I am now receiving this message:
"Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'.
Request Id: 3664ba82-beb3-4595-a59e-35c9c9a97b00
Correlation Id: 126a8aa9-a306-483f-8c18-759131c54e02
Timestamp: 2022-11-02T04:02:10Z
Message: AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'.
Flag sign-in errors for review: Enable flagging
If you plan on getting help for this problem, enable flagging and try to reproduce the error within 20 minutes. Flagged events make diagnostics available and are raised to admin attention."

Here is the current code:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import javax.crypto.Mac
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity

//Define credentials
def clientId = 'CLIENT_ID'
def clientSecret = 'CLIENT_SECRET'
def tenantId = 'TENANT-ID'

//Define url
def url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantId + '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?'
def body = '{"client_id":' + clientId + ',"response_type":"code","scope":"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default","client_secret":' + clientSecret + '}'
//StringEntity params = new StringEntity(body,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)

//Get current time
epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()

//Construct signature
requestVars = "POST" + epoch + body
hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
secret = new SecretKeySpec(clientSecret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256")
hmac.init(secret)
hmac_signed = Hex.encodeHexString(hmac.doFinal(requestVars.getBytes()))
signature = hmac_signed.bytes.encodeBase64()

//HTTP POST
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()
httpPost = new HttpPost(url)
httpPost.addHeader('Authorization', clientId + ':' + signature + ':' + epoch)
response = httpclient.execute(httpPost)
responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()

//Print Response
println 'Status: ' + code
println 'Body: ' + responseBody

httpclient.close()
```

Comment: i don't see where you are passing body into a post request. seems you are not sending body at all.

Comment: Body should be getting passed in the httpPost.addHeader(). Body gets rolled into requestVars, which gets encoded into signature, which is then passed in httpPost.addHeader(). Same process I use for another cloud system when doing a POST.

Of note, I did find changing this line:
def url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantId + '/oauth2/v2.0/token'
to this line:
def url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantId + '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?'
is now giving me a response stating client_id not being passed.

Comment: Could you reference the documentation you are following to authorize ? i used the flow described here and it works fine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code

Comment: btw. similar question but different library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244217/how-to-call-microsoft-graph-rest-api-with-groovy-wslite/73268561#73268561

Comment: I actually saw that, and tried using it as a reference, but the Groovy compiler kept throwing me an error with trying to grab wslite that I moved on to using a way I do it for another system. I was using the doc that poster outlined as my reference as well though. I should also note, that I normally use Powershell for accessing MSGraph, and that works fine. I'd like to move away from Powershell though as I need something OS agnostic, and Groovy is my only other option.

Comment: i want to say that documentation asking to send body as body and not as header. i don't see in your code any body in post request.